# Plotting trace while sampling in pymc

Tags: python, pymc

Is there any way to plot a a trace automatically  ever number of iterations?  I am working with a relatively expensive model and it would be nice to check the status of the chain every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

In PyMC 2.3, you can use `isample` in a console session (does not work in IPython Notebooks). This allows you to pause or send jobs to the background. It looks like this:

```
In [7]: M.isample(20000)
==============
 PyMC console
==============

        PyMC is now sampling. Use the following commands to query or pause the sampler.


        Commands:
          i -- index: print current iteration index
          p -- pause: interrupt sampling and return to the main console.
                      Sampling can be resumed later with icontinue().
          h -- halt:  stop sampling and truncate trace. Sampling cannot be
                      resumed for this chain.
          b -- bg:    return to the main console. The sampling will still
                      run in a background thread. There is a possibility of
                      malfunction if you interfere with the Sampler's
                      state or the database during sampling. Use this at your
                      own risk.

pymc > p
```

It can be a handy way of checking up on a long run.